# Type is not serializable because it's not public datacontractserializer

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, datacontractjsonserializer

I am new to wcf and windows phone 8 app and  calling wcf service(other dev) and trying to deserialize the data it works fine sometimes but most of the times it gives me error

> "The data contract type
>   'TEST.Model.Response`1[[TEST.Model.Announcement, TEST,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' cannot be
>   deserialized because the member 'ResponseData' is not public. Making
>   the member public will fix this error. Alternatively, you can make it
>   internal, and use the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute on your
>   assembly in order to enable serialization of internal members - see
>   documentation for more details. Be aware that doing so has certain
>   security implications."

MY Model Class is

```
public class Response<T> where T: class
{
    public string MethodName { get; set; }

    public int ResponseCode { get; set; }

    public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }

    public List<T> ResponseData { get; set; }

}

public class Announcement
{
    public int AnnouncementId { get; set; }

    public string AnnouncementTitle { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public string DataShortVersion { get; set; }

    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public string ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public int SortIndex { get; set; }
}
```

when i try to call as

```
var request = ar.AsyncState as WebRequest;
Stream reader = request.EndGetResponse(ar).GetResponseStream(); 

DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer ;\\
jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TEST.Model.Response<TEST.Model.Announcement>));
Response<Announcement> objResponse = (Response<Announcement>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(reader); //error raised
```

Comment: 1) pay attention to formatting of your question. 2) the code doesn't even compile. 3) did you *read* and *follow* the error message?

Comment: As mentioned in error I made all my member public but still gives me error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337278/wcf-is-serialization-of-a-generic-interfaces-possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) code below works. Try creating one yourself with your problem, and seeing how it is different than the one below. That will likely guide you to your answer.

```
public class StackOverflow_20806241
{
    public class Response<T> where T : class
    {
        public string MethodName { get; set; }
        public int ResponseCode { get; set; }
        public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
        public List<T> ResponseData { get; set; }
    }
    public class Announcement
    {
        public int AnnouncementId { get; set; }
        public string AnnouncementTitle { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string DataShortVersion { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public int SortIndex { get; set; }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string JSON = @"{'MethodName':'m1','ResponseCode':1,'ResponseMessage':'msg','ResponseData':[
            {'AnnouncementId':1,'AnnouncementTitle':'t1','CreatedBy':'c1','CreatedDate':'d1','DataShortVersion':'v1','ModifiedBy':'m1','ModifiedDate':'md1','SortIndex':1},
            {'AnnouncementId':2,'AnnouncementTitle':'t2','CreatedBy':'c2','CreatedDate':'d2','DataShortVersion':'v2','ModifiedBy':'m2','ModifiedDate':'md2','SortIndex':2}
        ]}";
        JSON = JSON.Replace('\'', '\"');
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JSON));
        DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer;
        jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response<Announcement>));
        try
        {
            var objResponse = (Response<Announcement>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(ms);
            Console.WriteLine("Response:");
            Console.WriteLine("  {0} - {1} - {2}", objResponse.MethodName, objResponse.ResponseCode, objResponse.ResponseMessage);
            Console.WriteLine("  [{0}]", string.Join(", ", objResponse.ResponseData.Select(rd =>
                string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}-{5}-{6}-{7}",
                    rd.AnnouncementId, rd.AnnouncementTitle,
                    rd.CreatedBy, rd.CreatedDate,
                    rd.DataShortVersion, rd.ModifiedBy,
                    rd.ModifiedDate, rd.SortIndex))));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: code is running async and hit the jsonSerializer.ReadObject(ms) line 2-3 times 1-2 times works fine but third times it gives me error.